# Replacing an iterated limit with a function depending on only one variable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Suppose
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{y\to\infty}f(x,y) = 0.
\qquad(\ast)
$$

I am wondering when there exists a function $x=g(y)$ such that (a) $\lim_{y\to\infty}g(y) = \infty$ and (b) $\lim_{y\to\infty}f(g(y),y) = 0$. **I do not assume that $f$ is uniformly continuous, that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)}f(x,y)$ exists, or that these limits can be interchanged.**

Instead of asking for conditions that guarantee this is possible, I wonder if there is a counterexample: Does there exist a function $f$ satisfying $(\ast)$ such that for every function $g$ satisfying (a), $\lim_{y\to\infty}f(g(y),y) \ne 0$?

Comment: Do you assume that $\displaystyle \lim_{y\to \infty} g(y) = \pm\infty$?

Comment: Should $g$ converge at all? Or do you also allow $g$s that don't converge?

Comment: Lets avoid these technicalities and simply assume $g(y)\to\infty$. (Edited question to reflect this.)

Comment: @JohnA This question is tricky because it is not clear how to find a good $g$ (and it is thus also not clear how to prove that there is no such $g$). Consider for instance $f(x,y):=\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ satisfying (*). If $g$ grows too quickly (for instance consider $g(y)=y$), then $\lim_{y\to\infty} f(g(y),y)\neq 0$. However, if $g$ grows slowly (for instance, $g(y)=\sqrt y$ for $y\geq 0$), then the limit does equal $0$.